# Python's subprocess.Popen() and source

Tags: python, bash

A third-party Python 2.5 script I'm trying to debug has got me stymied. The relevant part of the script is:

```
       proc = subprocess.Popen(
               "ls && source houdini_setup",
               shell = True,
               executable = "/bin/bash",
               )
```

There is a daemon that listens to port 5001 and runs the above script. When the script runs, it fails with the following error:

```
_cygwin.py
houdini_setup
... (more files) ...
/bin/sh: line 0: source: houdini_setup: file not found
```

There very much exists a file houdini_setup, as illustrated by the ls, and in fact if I change "source" to "cat" in the script above, the script prints the contents of houdini_setup as expected. Moreover, running the exact above command in a bona-fide bash shell also sources the file with no complaints.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I find the occurrence of null strange

Comment: I copy-pasted it from the code I'm trying to debug; deleting the line `stdin = null;` unfortunately makes no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`source` uses `$PATH` to find what you pass to it, if you don't specify a directory. Try `source ./houdini_setup`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

In a real bash shell, source doesn't need a ./ for files in the current directory, even when $PATH does not include said directory. Any idea why it's needed in Popen()?

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that the shell executing was actually sh, not bash, despite the line passed to the function call.

Comment: It has been my experience that it *is* needed. Always.

Comment: Even if it isn't needed, it should be.  Having . in the path is a configuration problem, and can lead to all kinds of badness and confusion.

Comment: @Andrew That argument only really applies to the executable PATH. There is no standard search path used by the source command any more than there is for e.g. ls. But while no ./ is needed in bash, it is needed by dash, which is these days commonly used as the implementation of the sh alias. Not sure why sh is being used despite the executable argument being passed in the OP question, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strace` to help diagnose problems like this. In this case running it with the `-ff` flag to follow subprocess would have revealed that your code was looking for "houdini_setup" in the wrong place:

```
stat64("/usr/local/bin/houdini_setup", 0xbf989e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/bin/houdini_setup", 0xbf989e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/bin/houdini_setup", 0xbf989e60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

That could have led you to check the documentation for the `source` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use bash itself to do the job, if it's available on your system:

```
os.popen("/bin/bash -l -c 'source $HOME/.yourfiletobesourced'")
```

Comment: You should still use the `subprocess` module to do that (with the `shell=True` keyword set).